# NSString not mantain value after "blanking" of a source NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

this is a more theoretical question than pratical;

Assuming that i have two Strings, one normal and one mutable, if i do:

```
NSMutableString *prova = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSString *prova2 = [[NSString alloc] init];
[prova appendFormat:@"%@",@"CIAO"];
prova2 = prova;
NSLog(@"String: %@",prova);
NSLog(@"String2: %@",prova2);
[prova setString:@""];
NSLog(@"-String: %@",prova);
NSLog(@"-String2: %@",prova2);
```

Then the result is:

```
2013-04-22 22:01:53.604 CodeTest[6974:303] String: CIAO
2013-04-22 22:01:53.605 CodeTest[6974:303] String2: CIAO
2013-04-22 22:01:53.605 CodeTest[6974:303] -String: 
2013-04-22 22:01:53.606 CodeTest[6974:303] -String2:
```

Why does it behave like this?
I just wanna find it out, because i've never encountered such thing before while programming in python, php or C++ (I think i was never confronted with so many different data types as in Obj-c :P )

Thanks

Just in case anyone wants to know how to get over it here is the right code i used to assign the value to the string without losing it after the "blanking" (sostitute to prova2 = prova):

```
prova2 = [NSString stringWithString:prova];
```

Comment: Ok, so you confirmed my doubts, i think i've lots of things to learn about obj-c. thank you all for the really fast answers :)

Comment: C++ also has pointers that work the same way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the `NSString` and `NSMutableString` variables are pointers.  That means when you assign `prova2 = prova` you're really changing `prova2` to point to `prova`, and the value you assigned to `prova2` is lost.

So when you assign the empty string to `prova` both variables point to `@""`.

Answer (score 1):

```
prova2 = prova;
```

This doesn't assign the contents of the string in `prova` to the string in `prova2`, it just makes `prova2` point to the same object as `prova`, effectively leaking the string that `prova2` used to point to. So even though `prova2` is declared as a `NSString*`, it now points to a `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Richard Brown's great response, that's what you'd like to do instead for desired behaviour:

```
[prova2 setString: prova];
```

instead of

```
prova2 = prova;
```

Comment: thanks, this is also better than the one i used and posted at the bottom.

Comment: but i can't get it working :( It gives me: "NSString may not respond to 'setString'" as warning, and then crashes when i invoke it.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I misread your code. setString: is method exclusively for NSMutableString. Two solutions: either change prova2 to be NSMutableString or to allocate it after prova (not before however, as this will be memory leak):
NSString* prova = [NSString stringWithString: prova2];